# How to get datetimepicker checked property?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetimepicker

There is a check box in the datetimepicker control of winforms .net. If a user clicks on the datetimepicker then the date should be saved otherwise null value should be stored in the database. Is there any way out?

I am using the following code:

```
if (dateDOB.Checked == true)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", dateDOB.Value.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", DBNull.Value);
        }
```

Comment: "is not working" is not a problem description. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and improve your question.

Comment: And what's wrong with your current code?

Comment: Sqlexception: Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

Comment: if your database does not accept NULL for this column you have to check specification first

Comment: It accepts NULL value but error takes place while inserting the date.

Comment: obviously the date is in the wrong format and can not be converted...so try to pass `dateDOB.Value` directly without converting it to string

Answer (score -2):

I would pass dateDob.Value.Date to strip off the time portion.